# In office 365 some text is bold but others not

Tags: html-email, office365

http://prntscr.com/7qaq9e

For some reason the same text sometimes shows as bold and other times not.  The code is the same, it works on other browsers with no issue, but on Outlook it seems to sometimes show bold.  Any ideas why?

Comment: Can you post the html and css?

Comment: I think I solved this.  It was either a screenshot issue, or an issue with the text inheriting from the containing `<td>`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that wasn't the issue to happens quite frequently.  It could be a space or an additional character somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specifically set `font-weight:normal;` on any text that is playing up.  I don't know why it changes some to bold and some to non-bold but I no longer have the issue.

I also ran my code through a validator and removed any links with `&` and converted to `&amp;` and fixed any errors (e.g. `<hr>` had no closing `<hr />`).  I suspect the former fixed it.

Comment: Interestingly in some email clients, I was getting an underline on the containing table and in some cases a double underline.  This resolved all of those issues too.  Probably my dodgy HTML that caused the issue although I can't fathom as to why it just underlined a table.